# Targetting multiple folder with Array in OUTLOOK VBA

Tags: vba, search, outlook

I'm very new to VBA and i'm strggling to finish my VBA macro.

I'm trying to use an array to execute a macro in 2/3 différent Outlook folders.

Here's my code :

```
Sub MarquerPostmasterNonLus()



Dim Fldr As Outlook.MAPIFolder, Fldr2 As Outlook.MAPIFolder, Fldr3 As Outlook.MAPIFolder           'On déclare que "FldrX" est un Dossier Outlook
Dim SFldr As Outlook.MAPIFolder                                                                    'On déclare que "SFldr" est un Sous-dossier Outlook
Dim Outlook As Object, NSpace As Object, Message As Object                      'On déclare "Outlook", "NSpace" et  les "Messages" comme étant des Objets
Dim DateReception As Date                                                       'On déclare ReceivedTime en Date
Set Outlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")                               'On définit ce qu'est "Outlook"
Set NSpace = Outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")                                       'On définit ce qu'est "NSpace"


Set Fldr = NSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("POSTMASTER")         'On définit le Dossier "Racine"
Set Fldr2 = NSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("ROBOT")             'Dossier 2
Set Fldr3 = NSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("MAILER-DAEMON")

Dim Ofldr As Variant
Ofldr = Array("Fldr2", "Fldr3")

'DOSSIER POSTMASTER
For Each SFldr In Fldr.Folders                                             'Pour chaque Sous-dossier dans le Dossier
    If SFldr.UnReadItemCount > 0 Then                                           'On cherche les Sous-dossier qui ont au moins 1 mail non-lu
      
        For Each Message In SFldr.Items                                         'Pour chaque Mail dans le Sous-dossier
            If TypeName(Message) = "MailItem" Then                              'On analyse seulement les items de type Mail

                    If Message.UnRead Then                                      'Si le Message est non-lu
                    DateReception = Format(Message.ReceivedTime, "dd/mm/yyyy")  'On Formatte la date de reception en dd/mm/yyyy
                    
                    If DateReception < Date Then                                'Si la date de récéption est antérieur à la date du jour
                        Message.UnRead = False                                  'On marque comme lu
                        
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End If
Next

'Autres dossiers
For Each Message In Ofldr.Items
    If Ofldr.UnReadItemCount > 0 Then
      
            If TypeName(Message) = "MailItem" Then

                    If Message.UnRead Then
                    DateReception = Format(Message.ReceivedTime, "dd/mm/yyyy")
                    
                    If DateReception < Date Then
                        Message.UnRead = False
                        
                    End If
                End If
            End If
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

I tried to create an Array with the following code :

```
Dim Ofldr As Variant
Ofldr = Array("Fldr2", "Fldr3")
```

But i alaways get an error when i execute the macro, and i can't figure it out !

The part of the code that needs to use the array is :

```
'Autres dossiers
For Each Message In Ofldr.Items
    If Ofldr.UnReadItemCount > 0 Then
      
            If TypeName(Message) = "MailItem" Then

                    If Message.UnRead Then
                    DateReception = Format(Message.ReceivedTime, "dd/mm/yyyy")
                    
                    If DateReception < Date Then
                        Message.UnRead = False
                        
                    End If
                End If
            End If
    End If
Next
```

If anyone could help me understand why this bit don't work, it would be awesome !

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

In the following code an array of strings is created:

```
Dim Ofldr As Variant
Ofldr = Array("Fldr2", "Fldr3")
```

So, the following line of code doesn't make any sense

```
For Each Message In Ofldr.Items
```

For the following reasons:

1. You are iterating over strings in the array, not the `Folder` objects.
2. A string variable doesn't provide the `Items` property.

If you really need the code working you need to declare an array of `Folder` objects by removing double quotes:

```
Ofldr = Array(Fldr2, Fldr3)
```

---

Anyway, I'd suggest using the `Find`/`FindNext` or `Restrict` methods of the `Items` class. They allow getting items that correspond to the specified search criteria and iterate over them only. Read more about these methods in the articles that I wrote for the technical blog:

- [How To: Use Find and FindNext methods to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder (C#, VB.NET)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/20/outlook-find-findnext-retrieve-mail/)
- [How To: Use Restrict method to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/23/outlook-restrict-method-retrieve-mail/)

But I've noticed that you need to process multiple folders in Outlook at once. In that case you may find the `AdvancedSearch` method of the `Application` class helpful. The key benefits of using the `AdvancedSearch` method in Outlook are:

- The search is performed in another thread. You don’t need to run another thread manually since the `AdvancedSearch` method runs it automatically in the background.
- Possibility to search for any item types: mail, appointment, calendar, notes etc. in any location, i.e. beyond the scope of a certain folder. The `Restrict` and `Find`/`FindNext` methods can be applied to a particular `Items` collection (see the `Items` property of the `Folder` class in Outlook).
- Full support for DASL queries (custom properties can be used for searching too). To improve the search performance, Instant Search keywords can be used if Instant Search is enabled for the store (see the `IsInstantSearchEnabled` property of the `Store` class).
- You can stop the search process at any moment using the `Stop` method of the `Search` class.

See [Advanced search in Outlook programmatically: C#, VB.NET](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2012/05/31/outlook-search-csharp-vbnet/) for more information.

Comment: Hi, thank you for answering !
I'll definitely try that ! 
It will take me some time to understand it but i have to give it a try !